# Generate random number withing a git commit statement

Tags: bash, git

I can commit and push something **in the past** using:

```
git commit --date="25 day ago" -m "some message"
```

I would like to generate a command that takes the parameter `--date="___ day ago"` as a random date in the last `360 day ago` interval.

How can I approach the problem?

Comment: Why would you *want* a random date? The purpose of `--date` is to allow a patch written by one person but committed by another to have accurate author and committer dates, not to vandalize the commit history with meaningless values.

Comment: I am not **vandalizing** any history of my personal repository. I just want to understand how to assign a random variable to the parameter `--date` in a git commit. Moreover, if I did so, what kind of statistical distribution is used to create the `$RANDOM % 360`: gaussian?  Uniform? can I further specify?

Comment: What use is a random commit date?

Comment: if you **were** a statistician, you could simulate x amount of randomly distributed commits on a repo, and retrospectively match it back with the real commits in the last 360 days. Wanna go deeper?

Comment: If you are a statistician, you aren't using the shell's `RANDOM` variable for a study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bash, you can:

```
git commit --date="$(( $RANDOM % 360 )) days ago" -m "some message"
```

Comment: thanks! but how can I see at what day the commit was actually submitted, given $RANDOM as a random variable (what distribution tho?)

Comment: You can `git show` to see the date. You can assign to a variable, echo the variable before you make the commit and then use the variable. The distribution is not explicitly specified ("a random integer between 0 and 32767 is generated"), so I assume it is uniform.

Comment: thanks! It might be gaussian tho. Let me check further.

Comment: Bash `RANDOM` is a 15-bit integer. It holds values between 0 and 32767 with a somewhat even distribution. So it distributes 32768 random values. If you do reminder of 32768%360 you get 8 which means, out of 365 days selected the first 8 days have 8/91 more chance to get selected.  I means it cannot be trusted for serious statistics, or security because Bash `RANDOM ` is a very poor random source.

Comment: meaning that I can't define something like `--date="$(( $RANDOM % 120 )) days ago"`? But `% 180` will work

Comment: No, it just means that if you need an absolutely uniform distribution, then you should not do `% 360`, but if you do not care that *some* values have a *slightly* different chance to occur, then `% 360` is one way to do it. Constructing a perfectly uniform distribution from a given discrete distribution requires more work.